# Alphabet in multiple languages in .NET

Tags: .net, text

Does .NET contain Alpha Numeric Table, or Alphabet of different Languages?

E.G: System.Text.Encoding.LatinAlphabet?

Or is it the case that Alphabets need to be collected and put into a Class separately?

Comment: AFAIK .NET just contains ordering definitions for particular locales. Why do you need alphabets like that?

Comment: I am implementing a Char Mapping procedure for Machine Learning App